# jQuery: Total values in textboxes automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of textboxes with the following IDs:

```
118|1/9/2011
118|1/10/2011
118|1/11/2011
118|1/12/2011
118|1/13/2011
118|1/14/2011
118|1/15/2011
118|Total
```

Using jQuery or just javascript, I need to sum each textbox and assign the value to the total textbox. This needs to happen when a user tabs off or clicks off the textbox. It also needs to be generic enough to handle textboxes with similar IDs such as:

```
119|1/9/2011
119|1/10/2011
119|1/11/2011
119|1/12/2011
119|1/13/2011
119|1/14/2011
119|1/15/2011
119|Total
```

The format stays the same. Only the first numbers to the left of the | will change.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [IDs of HTML elements must begin with a letter, and can contain neither vertical bars nor slashes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: Well I've used the same convention for the name attribute for each textbox as well.

Comment: Can you specify a class for the inputs you want to sum?

Comment: Sure. I can do anything to make this easier. Just need some code to get started. I'm having a brain freeze at the moment not to mention I'm not that great at jquery.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, that's true of html 4; I understand the rules are a little different for html 5.

Comment: @David, yes, HTML5 allows any character in `id` and `name` attributes, except `space`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**: I updated my answer to reflect the actual example HTML that Mike provided, which you can view in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avidal/zfjmD/). That link also contains the working javascript from below.

---

If you have a specific selector for the inputs you want to sum (like a class name), as well as one for the total, you should be able to do this (here's a fiddle link with this javascript in action: http://jsfiddle.net/avidal/zfjmD/):

```
$('input.sum').change(function() {
    var sum = 0;

    // we want to sum up the values of all input.sum elements that are in the same tr
    // as this one
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input.sum').each(function(i) {
        var val = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        /*
        change the above line to:
        var val = parseFloat($(this).val());
        if the inputs will be floats
        */
        if (isNaN(val) || val === undefined) {
            return;
        }

        sum += val;
    });

    $(this).closest('tr').find('input.total').val(sum);

});
```

The important things to note are the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function, and the [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function.

First, we bind to the `change` event for all inputs with a class of sum. When one of those elements is changed (the value changes, then the user clicks/tabs out), we look for the `closest` `tr` element, then `find` the list of inputs with a class of sum that are children of that `tr`. For `each` of those inputs, we parse the value and accumulate the `sum`. After we've iterated over `each` of those inputs, we finally find the input with a class of total that's a descendant of the closest tr, and set the `val` of that input to the accumulated `sum`

Perfect!

Comment: How do I specify or where do I specify a different parent element for the different series of inputs?

Comment: BTW - The series of inputs are dynamically generated.

Comment: @Mike: I updated my answer to show some sample HTML that works with the javascript I posted. As long as each group of inputs (dynamically generated or not) are enclosed in a separate parent element, this will work.

Comment: Does it matter if these inputs are in a table row in separate <td>'s?

Comment: @Mike: Whoa, that's some ugly HTML. I'll try to simplify it slightly, then adjust the code to compensate.

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle link with properly formatted html code. I've added an id to the <tr>. Could that be used as a parent element? I don't think I can have <div>'s in the table html code.

Comment: @Mike: Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avidal/zfjmD/, also, updated my answer to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Great question and great answer! This works perfectly! To answer Mike, I changed 'tr' to 'table' in the jQuery and it totals all the sums in a table across several tr's and td's. As long as the inputs have the class="sum" they will be totaled.